# Parse Parcel from 2 activities to 1 ListActivity

Tags: android

I have 3 activities: 1 is QuickAddActivity, 2 is DetailedAddActivity, 3 is a ListView Activity.
Both 1 and 2 need to send Parcel to add item in 3. However, if I getIntent() from both, there is NullException Error

```
ArrayList<Parcelable> detailedParcelables = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra(AddTaskActivity.DETAILED_TASK);
        mTasks = new Task[detailedParcelables.size()];
        detailedParcelables.toArray(mTasks);

        ArrayList<Parcelable> quickParcelables = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra(MainActivity
                .QUICK_TASK);
        mTasks = new Task[quickParcelables.size()];
        quickParcelables.toArray(mTasks);
```

If I use only 1, it's OK to add item to the ListView.
What can I do?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. One activity can only handle one launch intent at a time. Where is your error?

Comment: But this case If I put  these code, the app wont handle any intent but crash immediately when I click a button.